# Javascript circular buffer queue implementation as a "FIFO queue"

Tags: javascript, node.js, queue, v8, fifo

Is there a circular buffer version of array? Assuming number of max pushed elements at time is known, do I have to derive my own FIFO queue for performance?

Here is what I tried:

Circular implementation:

```
function CBuf(n)
{
    var ctrPush=0;
    var ctrPop=0;
    var ab = new ArrayBuffer(n*4);
    var buf = new Uint32Array(ab);

    this.push = function (v) {
        buf[ctrPush%n] = v;
        ctrPush++;
    };


    this.empty = function () {
         return (ctrPush == ctrPop);
    }


    this.pop = function () {
        var tmp = buf[ctrPop%n];
        ctrPop++;
        return tmp;
    };
}
```

Benchmark simple array:

```
{
    var t1 = new Date();
    var arr = [];

    for (var j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            arr.push(i); 
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            arr.shift();
        }
    }
    var t2 = new Date();

    console.log("array time=" + (t2 - t1));
}
```

Benchmark circular buffer:

```
{
    var t1 = new Date();
    var arr = new CBuf(10000);

    for (var j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            arr.push(i);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            if(!arr.empty())
                arr.pop();
        }
    }
    var t2 = new Date();

    console.log("cbuf time="+(t2 - t1));
}
```

Result:

```
array time=2749 ms
cbuf time=552 ms (230 if using &(n-1) instead of %n)
```

For max 70k elements:

```
array time=19456 ms
cbuf time=3872 ms (1700 if using &(n-1) instead of %n)
```

they seem to have similar time complexity but array shift is slower in Nodejs. Maybe it check many things like bounds checking and resizing constantly? I need something like a  SIMD variable but with n length.

I'm planning on using this on a nodejs inter-server work scheduler queue.

**Edit:**

Here you can test:

https://jsperf.com/fifo-array-vs-circular-buffer-preallocated

Comment: What you want is something like a plain array but what you **don't** want is to be shifting the array contents back and forth, as those are linear operations. Just keep your own index values for the start and end of the circular buffer.

Comment: Careful: `&(n-1)` is not the same as `%n` unless `n` is a power of 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push and shift are slow. Just use an array index.

Comment: Minor correction: Push is fast. Shift is slow. Something index-based like the suggested `CBuf` implementation is the way to go (but beware of overflow!).